# Does Jmeter update the change the DB

Tags: jmeter

In my application, when ever a user logs in, the application captures the users login time.

while running a recorded script, if the user needs to login, in my DB the script run time doesn't come. it shows the old time itself. Does running Jmeter doesn't have any impact on the Database?

Answer (score 0):

It reveals certainly an error in your script.

Use a View Result Tree and see if response are the same as the one you get when you record.

You certainly missed some dynamic parameter, header or so.